# AngularJS Map one object to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to map a `$scope.filters` object to a `var criteria` on the condition if the original fields are null or not.

So lets say I have:

```
$scope.filters = {
    name: 'myName'
    lastName: null,
    age: null,
}
```

I want my `var criteria` to be mapped to non null fields like this:

```
var criteria = {
    name: 'myName';
}
```

So I have tried like this:

```
var criteria = {};

angular.forEach($scope.filters, function (value, key, obj) {
        if (value != null) {
            this.push(obj)
        }
}, criteria);
```

But I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: What are you `push`ing onto? Your `$scope.filters` is an Object, not an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`criteria` is an object, not an array, so you can't push it. Either make it an array if you want to store separate individual criteria, or replace the push with `this[key] = value;`

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this,

```
$scope.filters = {
  name: 'myName'
  lastName: null,
  age: null,
 }

var criteria = []; //array, you were using object
    angular.forEach($scope.filters, function(value, key) {
      if (value != null) {
            this.push(key + ': ' + value);
        }

    }, criteria);  

expect(criteria).toEqual(['name: myName']);
```

Hope it helps.